# Database.insert(list,false) in apex

Tags: apex, database.insert

I am creating List of Accounts, using `database.inser(list,false)` if i did give name for record in list,it will skip that particular and insert remaining records, is there any chance to get the details of skipped record.

Comment: You can get that using `Database.saveresult` which will have the failed records as well

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Please check the following link of how to access the error records: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm

Comment: Posting links as answers doesn't help. Links fail or become dead all the time.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. For me, it was important to know exactly which inserted object succeeded or failed. I wrote some methods to handle this:

```
/**
     * @description Method to insert objects to DataBase with improved audit
     * @param sObjects - sObjects to be insert
     * @param field - field that identifies Saveresult with inserted object
     * @return map where key is a value from field specified as param: field
     * and the value is Save result for sObject which is identified by key
     */
    public static Map<String,Database.SaveResult> improvedInsert(List<SObject> sObjects, Schema.sObjectField field) {
        Map<String,Database.SaveResult> saveResultByField = new Map<String,Database.SaveResult>();
        List<Database.SaveResult> results = Database.insert(sObjects, false);
        for (Integer i = 0;i<sObjects.size();i++) {
            saveResultByField.put((String)sObjects.get(i).get(field),results.get(i));
        }
        return  saveResultByField;
    }
```

Methods give you a map where key is specified as parameter field value and the value is referencing Save/Upsert Result object.

Comment: Post relevant content to your answer or delete it. Links are not valuable here especially when they go stale

Answer (score 3):

Find the below code refer [link](https://trailhead-salesforce-com.firelayers.net/apex_database/apex_database_dml)

> The Database methods return result objects containing success or
> failure information for each record. For example, insert and update
> operations each return an array of `Database.SaveResult` objects.

```
Database.SaveResult[] saveResultList = Database.insert(insertList, false);

// Iterate through saveResultList based on isSuccess capture the failed records
for (Database.SaveResult sr : saveResultList) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully inserted account. Account ID: ' + sr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "if (!sr.isSuccess()) { " should be without the !